# MySQL Cluster -- Storing table data on data nodes

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Cluster — Storing table data on data nodes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/mysql-cluster-storing-table-data-on-data-nodes)

I have setup MySQL Cluster with the MySQL server node and the Management node on a single server, and 2 data nodes (each on a different server for 3 servers in all). After installing, I run ndb_mgm and run SHOW at the prompt and everything seems to look OK, with the following headers.

```
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
```

When I run mysql -uroot on the mysql server and create a database and populate a table with data I notice that the database directory and table files are being created in the local datadir, not the datadir on my Cluster's data nodes.

I have set /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini to point at the data nodes and their datadir. The /etc/my.cnf file looks like this on all 3 servers. I have hidden the DNS, both are the same

```
[mysqld]
# Options for mysqld process:
ndbcluster                      # run NDB storage engine
ndb-connectstring=domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx #location of management server

[mysql_cluster]
# Options for ndbd process:
ndb-connectstring=domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx #location of management server
```

Why is the mysql table data files being stored locally? Shouldn't the data files (.ndb and .frm files) be on the data nodes only?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible this is a permissions issue? Data dir owner on the data node is mysql. And I'm creating the database as --user=root on the mysql server

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. I posted it on stack overflow first. Commenters there said it should be posted on dba stack exchange, which I did. Then someone migrated the question. Nonetheless, the question remains. Thanks.